# Trying to remember a dinosaur book

Tags: story-identification, books, time, dinosaurs

From what I remember, a guy is transported back in time, a time before dinosaurs. He is told to only travel on certain paths. When he breaks this rule, he bends a blade of grass that a dragonfly/butterfly was supposed to land on and be eaten by some lizard. Since this event doesn't happen, evolution is forever changed. The protagonist finds himself in a land of dinosaurs but now they can talk verbally, they have a government and such, basically dinosaurs evolved into the dominant species. The protagonist is captured by a raptor and taken back to the raptor civilization and is imprisoned there. Can't remember the title of this book.  I would recognize the cover of the paperback if I saw it.  Any ideas?  It's not Thomas Hopps' *Dinosaur Wars* although the there are some similarities...

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Are there any other details you can remember, for example, when you read it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Story involving a time machine in a museum and butterflies](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/story-involving-a-time-machine-in-a-museum-and-butterflies)

Comment: @JohnRennie We're not supposed to dupe-close story ID questions until both original and dupe have accepted answers.

Comment: @randal'thor: the question seems to me an obvious duplicate, and the previous question has an excellent answer with 14 upvotes. If you're saying I shouldn't flag this as a duplicate because the previous OP couldn't be bothered to mark their question as answered then I have to say I disagree with you. Perhaps this is my rebellious spirit, but I like to think of it as common sense.

Comment: @JohnRennie I hate to sound like a bureaucrat, but what I said is the current community consensus and not just my opinion :-) If you can make a good argument for your case, you could try doing so on meta. Unfortunately 'obvious duplicate' isn't very easy to define with story ID questions: sometimes an answer can seem like it must be right and then the OP says it isn't after all!

Comment: @randal'thor: in that case no-one else will VTC and my single vote will have done no harm.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Frank's answer, there was a book series based on "A Sound of Thunder", "Ray Bradbury presents Dinosaur World" (actually written by Stephen Leigh). The plot continued the story, and the first one did indeed have the main characters being captured by intelligent dinosaurs, although they were ornithiomimids rather than raptors.

[image]

There were several black & white interior illustrations by Wayne Barlowe. Here's one of the intelligent dinos:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many similar stories and books.  I'm not sure of the one you described.  But Ray Bradbury wrote a short story "A Sound of Thunder".  People are taken on hunting tours in the past.  They kill dinosaurs that are about to die, and they must stay on a path.  One guy runs off the path.  He ends up stepping on a butterfly.  When they return to the future they find things subtly different.  But there are no intelligent dinosaurs in that story.