# Time travel movie where travelers in the time of the dinosaurs accidentally change the timeline

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie on Syfi maybe 8-10 years ago where people were able to travel back in time to the age of the dinosaurs. They had to stay on this bridge type thing and not step off or touch anything to avoid a butterfly effect. Someone stepped off and killed a bug, and when they got back to their own time, the timeline started changing. Anyone know the name of the movie?

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124047/time-traveler-steps-on-a-butterfly-changes-everything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Story involving a time machine in a museum and butterflies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55485/story-involving-a-time-machine-in-a-museum-and-butterflies)

Comment: @JamesK Please note we don't close story-id questions as duplicate until they have an accepted answer.  Also, I'm not sure if a question about a movie is really a duplicate of a question about a short story, even if the movie is based on the story, because there can be more than one adaptation.

Answer (score 24):

Ray Bradbury's [short story](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?61488) ["A Sound of Thunder"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sound_of_Thunder) was adapted [as a movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sound_of_Thunder_(film)) in 2005.

Unique to this adaptation of the story (different from the short story and the previous adaptation for [*The Ray Bradbury Theater*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ray_Bradbury_Theater)) is that the timeline changes don't immediately manifest when the adventurers return, but propogate uptime in waves, which seems to match what you describe.

There is a brief plot description (in contrast to Wikipedia's ridiculously detailed one) on [IMDb](https://imdb.com/title/tt0318081/):

> When a scientist sent back to the prehistoric era strays off the path he causes a chain of events that alters history in disastrous ways.