# Time travel to a reptilian civilisation at the time of the dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, dinosaurs

I read this story about 20 years ago, but it could be older. It was in a small book by itself, not a collection, probably a paperback. But it was rather short for a novel, maybe a novella.

I am positive I read it in French, but of course it may be a translation from any language.

No "capture and imprison" of a single woman. An entire team of humans from the future is met as welcome visitors by humanoid dinosaurs, friendship all around.

A scientific institute receives some mysterious signals. For some reason I forgot they conclude it does not come from far away in space, but from the past on Earth. More specifically, from the time of the dinosaurs. They develop a time machine (or maybe, they already had a time machine but had never used it so far back ?) and travel to the time they think these signals come from. And indeed, they find an advanced civilisation of vaguely humanoid dinosaurs which indeed had sent signals to the future in the hope of contacting a future civilisation. The dinosaurs scientists know about the trajectory of the asteroid that will hit Earth and threatens to destroy them. I don't remember more details, not what the end is, but of course they were not able to do anything to save their civilisation.

---

EDIT

Since I posted this question I became aware of a similar looking one [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14885/title-of-a-sci-fi-book-with-time-travel-and-sentient-dinosaurs?rq=1)

But it is definitely **not** my story.
No "capture and imprison" of a single woman. An entire team of humans from the future is met as welcome visitors by humanoid dinosaurs, friendship all around.

Comment: In case it was a French novel rather than a translation, you could look over https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction_préhistorique and see if any titles look familiar

Comment: @Hypnosifl Well, this list is pretty long. Without any details but the title, I did not see anything that rang a bell. Which does not mean it is not there, just that no title seemed more promising than any other...